# TinyMCE Inline leaves garbage code behind

Tags: javascript, tinymce, inline

Is there an "easier" way or something within TinyMCE to remove the junk code it leaves behind FOR INLINE?

```
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="thumbnail" data-type="imagewrap">
          <div spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" id="mce_20" data-type="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://os.dev/pets4you.com/httpdocs/pages/demo/images/09-29-2011edokkomoki.jpg" alt="" data-mce-src="http://os.dev/pets4you.com/httpdocs/pages/demo/images/09-29-2011edokkomoki.jpg"></div>
          <div spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" id="mce_26" data-type="caption"><h4>Edokko's Moki</h4>Chocolate Silver</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Specifically this junk:

spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" id="mce_26"

AND

data-mce-src="http://os.dev/pets4you.com/httpdocs/pages/demo/images/09-29-2011edokkomoki.jpg"

As of right now I have to destroy it, then run through the tags and remove them from each element. Really would like to remove that step.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by `FOR INLINE` ?

Comment: Meaning inline editing. Not div or textarea editing.